# Anaconda2 Installation Error

Tags: python, anaconda

I deleted the ~/anaconda2 directory by accident and couldn't get it back.

Trying to reinstall anaconda2:

`./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86.sh`

After going through everything i get the following error which I don't understand...

```
PREFIX=/home/mike/anaconda2
installing: python-2.7.14-h41cc02d_21 ...
./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86.sh: 358: ./Anaconda2-5.0.1-Linux-x86.sh: /home/mike/anaconda2/pkgs/python-2.7.14-h41cc02d_21/bin/python: not found
```

Any ideas?

I actually did :

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
rm -rf ~/.anaconda/navigator
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
nano ~/.bash_profile # remove the anaconda directory from your `PATH` env var
remove the shortcut from the applications folder
```

to safely uninstall.

But still getting that error. I'm guessing its remnents from the old installation.

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/74 dude seems to have the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

Your python path is probably still set to Anaconda python. Try restarting your shell or executing

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and check if error goes away.